# Showing that pseudorapidity equals $\ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{p_z^2 + p_t^2}+p_z}{p_t}\right)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics, momentum

I found one method to calculate pseudorapidity, $\eta$, using the formula
\begin{equation}
 \eta = - \ln  \tan \frac{\theta}{2}
\end{equation}
And I know how we can get to this point from [Lecture 7 - Rapidity and Pseudorapidity in these notes](http://www.hep.shef.ac.uk/edaw/PHY206/Site/2012_course_files/phy206rlec7.pdf).

But how can we get from there to this formula?
\begin{equation}
\eta = \ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{p_z^2 + p_t^2}+p_z}{p_t}\right)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [trigonometric identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae) for the tangent of a half angle
$$\tan\frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{\sin\theta}{1 + \cos\theta}$$
which you can use to expand the first formula.
Then it's just geometry.

[image: relation of momenta for emitted particle]

Answer (score -1):

Oh Maybe I have found,

Another formula for the pseudorapidity $\eta$ is :

\begin{equation}
\eta = \ln \frac{p+p_z}{p-p_z} \\
\eta = \ln \dfrac{\sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2}+pz}{\sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2}-p_z} \\
\eta = \ln \dfrac{\sqrt{p_x^2 +p_y^2 + 2 \times p_z^2}}{\sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2}} \\
\end{equation}

So We can find :

\begin{equation}
\eta = \ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{p_\perp^2 +p_z^2}+p_z}{p_\perp} \right)
\end{equation}

**This is wrong, the transition between line 3 and 4 are illegal mathematically**

Comment: How did you get from the second to the third equation? That doesn't seem to work out mathematically.

Comment: $p_z = \sqrt{p_z^2}$ after $\sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2} + \sqrt{p_z^2} = \sqrt{p_x^2 +p_y^2 + 2 \times p_z^2}$

Comment: Yeah, that's not valid. $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} \neq \sqrt{a + b}$

Comment: Hum, I think I was tired to say that ...