# Calculating the Pseudorapidity from Three-Momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics

in one of our Particle Physics exercises, we're supposed to calculate the pseudorapidity of a particle produced at a hadron collider with a three-momentum $\vec p = \left( p_x, p_y, p_z\right) = \left( 30, 40, 50\right)$ GeV. As a hint, we're given that

> $\theta$ can be obtained by $\frac{p_T}{p_z}$

which confuses me. *I* thought that $$\cos\theta = \frac{p_z}{\left| \vec p \right|}.   \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad [1]$$

Which of the equations is now actually correct? In this concrete case, they yield different values for the pseudorapidity.

I have the [following CMS coordinate](https://wiki.physik.uzh.ch/cms/_detail/latex:cms_coordinate_system.png?id=latex%3Atikz) system in mind:

[image]

Comment: Pseudorapity at the LHC is not the $\theta$ you know from spherical coordinates (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorapidity )

Comment: Oh my, now I see, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, but now I feel confused: In the answer to this question (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/279175/showing-that-pseudorapidity-equals-ln-left-frac-sqrtp-z2-p-t2p-zp), there is a triangle drawn from which $\cos\theta = p_z/\left|\vec p\right|$ would follow ...

Comment: There, $\theta$ is again the angle in polar coordinate. But you want to compute the pseudorapity (which your exercise seems to call $\theta$) which is usually denoted by $\eta$. But I have to admit I do not see how the formula given in your exercise follows.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but there seems to be a misunderstanding: The exercise still calls the pseudorapidity $\eta$! I suspect they want us to calculate $\theta$ first and then $\eta$ by using the Eq. $\eta = -\ln \tan \frac{\theta}{2}$.

Comment: Ahh, good to know. Then, your formula for $\cos\theta$ is correct, using $p_T/p_z$ is just another way to compute it. If you want to compute this, try using spherical coordinates and $p_T=\sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2}$.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!