# Follow-Up Question to "Calculating the Pseudorapidity from Three-Momentum"

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics

I have a follow-up question [to my own question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/595569/calculating-the-pseudorapidity-from-three-momentum?noredirect=1#comment1340228_595569): In there, I wrote that at a hadron collider, $$\theta = \frac{p_T}{p_z}.$$ Why does this Eq. actually hold, i.e. how can we derive it? From [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/279175/showing-that-pseudorapidity-equals-ln-left-frac-sqrtp-z2-p-t2p-zp), I found this nice picture:

[image]

Do we then say that $\tan\left( \theta \right) \approx \theta$ for small angles $\theta$?

Comment: Yes, If you'll make Taylor series expansion about zero of basic trigonometric functions like $\sin \cos \tan$, you will see that first term will be just they argument $x$. Thus $\tan(x) \approx x$, for $x \to 0$.

Comment: Oops, I was wrong for $\cos()$. First non-constant term of Taylor series expansion about zero would be $1-\frac{x^2}{2}$. But for $\sin \tan$ it's $x$ as I've said.